# Unable to scan Barcode using Google vision library for one plus 7 Android Q

Tags: java, android, google-vision

I have Implemented Google vision Library(V-17.0.2) and it is working fine too. But for One Plus 7 Andorid Q barcode is not getting scanned and not getting any error also.

I tried `barcode.isOperational()` on emulator it returns true for Nexus and Pixel containing Android Q and for One Plus 7 returning false.

Comment: That library has been deprecated for some time now, It was replaced with Firebase MLKit

Comment: Hey Vaishali, this is not an answer but an alternative you can use https://github.com/dm77/barcodescanner this lib. We are using this. it's working fine.